# Adding custom header with volley request and response is "data": "This field is required"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

i am just started with volley request with custom request here is peace of code what i am using for sending a custom header. headers must be
                **headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");**

When i am hitting this url with postman it is working fine.

**row data in postman**
[image: row data in postman Image]

and
Headers
[image: Headers Image]

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            WebConstants.BASE_URL + method,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    if (dialog != null)
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    if (response != null) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("res", response);
                        //    eventHandler.onResponse("" + method, response);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (dialog != null)
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    eventHandler.onResponse("" + method, "");
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            String str = "{\"firstname\":\"Test\", \"lastname\":\"User\", \"gender\":\"male\", \"country\":\"US\", \"zipcode\":\"H1A NFG\", \"email\":\"testuseef434532r@mail.com\", \"password\":\"123456\", \"referral_code\":\"\", \"requested_plan\":\"\"}";
            return str.getBytes();

        }

/* Tried with this
@Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("firstname","Sandeep");
                    jsonObject.put("lastname","Parish");
                    jsonObject.put("gender","M");
                    jsonObject.put("country","US");
                    jsonObject.put("zipcode","H1A NFG");
                    jsonObject.put("email","usermail@localmail.com");
                    jsonObject.put("password","123456");
                    jsonObject.put("referral_code","123456");
                    jsonObject.put("requested_plan","123456");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return jsonObject.toString().getBytes();

            }

//Tried with map
  @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("firstname", "sandeep");
        map.put("lastname", "sada");
        map.put("gender", "d");
        map.put("country", "sdfasiio");
        map.put("zipcode", "test");
        map.put("email", "testmail@mail.com");
        map.put("password", "0");
        map.put("referral_code", "0");
        map.put("requested_plan", "0");

        Log.e("Map", map.toString());
                return map;
            }
*/

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

    };


    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

please help me to find out what's the issue with this code i am getting  response with this code is.

```
E/res: {
        "success": false,
        "data": "This field is required"
    }
```

if any issue at my side please let me know.

Comment: how you use it with postman? Can you show the screenshot?

Comment: you should send body parameters as key value pair instead of json string

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko added that and Vivek let me check with your solution.

Comment: show the body of the request. I want to check how you send the data

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks but issue not resolved yet

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i am adding my json in row data field.

Comment: so you send it as body, not as a part of multipart, right? can't see the top of the window

Comment: That's not what I meant. Send them as key value pair in form of a map object and if that doesn't work try with JsonObjectRequest in place of String Request

Comment: this is not a multi part request this api is only for user signup with personal details.all are text fields.

Comment: @VivekMishra please let me knw when my server side code accept data in json format then how can i post data in map, it will show basic network perform exception.

Comment: Try with json object request if that doesn't work

Comment: not yet, please wait i am tried to do same as well you suggest

Comment: @VivekMishra  map object  not working attached with code check if i am doing wrong.

Comment: Does it gives same issue ?

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes,Same issue

Comment: i think header is not attaching with this,please let me know if your found why not.

Comment: try with json Object request. Seems like your server will only accept it in json form.

Comment: i also tried with json object please check above code what i tried with this code.

Comment: No that's not what I mean. Volley provides different type of requests. You are currently using String Request. I am saying to change that to JsonObjectRequest

Comment: it seems here is issue with header , when in debug it show body content properly but not showing header data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        WebConstants.BASE_URL + method,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("firstname", "sandeep");
      map.put("lastname", "sada");
     map.put("gender", "d");
    map.put("country", "sdfasiio");
    map.put("zipcode", "test");
    map.put("email", "testmail@mail.com");
    map.put("password", "0");
    map.put("referral_code", "0");
    map.put("requested_plan", "0");

    Log.e("Map", map.toString());
            return map;
        }
};
stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: What you change in it